# Is there a way to revert my mysql database after a Laravel Dusk migration rollback?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-dusk

I was starting to learn how to properly use Dusk to make browser tests and I accidentally ran a test class which had `use DatabaseMigration;` in it and it ran on my local dev db instead of the testing db.

Is there a way to revert this? I'm using Laravel 8.2 and MySql 8.0.29.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening in the future? Like a check or something?

Thank you.

Comment: If you dont backups - you have a trouble. people are divided into two types - those who do not yet make backups and those who ALREADY do

Comment: I worked in photography before and I tend to respect the 3-2-1 backup. This however is non-important data, I have a months old image of the data and the migrations are safe. It is mostly going to be a bit of a hunt to retrieve last week's transactions which were entries to make a demo. So that was the only important info on my dev DB for this app, the rest was just nice to have. I was just wondering if there were alternatives that could cut down on this restore process even if it wasn't perfect. I have a plan for a NAS but I'm still gathering the funds to make that happen.